# Bluetooth api in windows phone 7 or mango

Tags: bluetooth, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to list out the bluetooth devices in the range with windows phone 7 programmatically. Also is it possible to do it with mango sdk?

Answer (score 5):

There is no bluetooth API in 7.0 or 7.1.
You cannot write apps which work with Bluetooth devices unless you're an OEM or operator.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "Apollo". you need to wait till windows phone 8 is released.

Comment: Details of the functionality available to developers in WP8 has not yet been made public. Be careful what you claim.

Comment: Fortunately, he is right :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207007(v=vs.105).aspx